# Bootstrap tabs with anchor behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, tabs, anchor

I'm using the bootstrap tabs to organize courses of a site (http://goo.gl/AEgyEc)

The `<nav class="nav-courses">` works divided into 3 tabs "Undergraduate Courses", "Postgraduate Courses" and "Extension Courses." These links have the same function of `<ul id="#menu-courses">`, activating the flaps.

However, beyond just activate, the site must scroll to the id of the anchor. For example, clicking on Undergraduate Courses should scroll to the anchor `#tab-graduation`. However, this behavior only works when the tab is already active (double-clicking). Is there any way to activate and roll along?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the code below:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-graduation" onClick="jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href=#tab-graduation]').tab('show')">Cursos Graduação</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-graduate" onClick="jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href=#tab-graduate]').tab('show')">Cursos Pós-graduação</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-extension" onClick="jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href=#tab-extension]').tab('show')">Cursos Extensão</a></li>
</ul>
```

Maybe it will help someon ;)

Answer (score 0):

if your using the bootstrap content, you should just be doing it this way, theres no need for the onclick. You will only see the content if you clicked the right tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
   <li><a href="#graduation" data-toggle="tab">graduation</a></li>
   <li><a href="#graduate" data-toggle="tab">graduate</a></li>
   <li><a href="#extension" data-toggle="tab">extension</a></li>
</ul>   
<div class="tab-content" id="TabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduation">
      <p>
         graduation content
      </p>
   </div>      
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduate">
      <p>
         graduate
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="extension">
       <p>
          extension
       </p>
    </div>
</div>
```